# metpy interpolate_to_grid not working for me with simple data

Tags: python, interpolation, metpy

I have an issue when adapting a simple dataset to generate temperature interpolation map from points

```
#!apt-get update
#!apt-get -qq install python-cartopy python3-cartopy

#!pip install metpy
```

installed dependecies as using a colab notebook

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

!curl "https://climaya.com/fp-weather/api/api.php?q=GT_forecast&d=3" > data.json
df = pd.read_json("data.json")
#df

lat=df['latitude'].values
lon=df['longitude'].values
#lat,lon
```

this gives an array of lat, lon

```
mapcrs=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-90)
datacrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mapcrs)
ax.scatter(lon,lat,c=df['temp_high'].values*1,transform=datacrs)
```

this shows the data points ok

[image]

```
from metpy.interpolate import interpolate_to_grid, remove_nan_observations

lon=df['longitude'].values*1.
lat=df['latitude'].values*1.
dat=df['temp_high'].values*1.0

#lon,lat,dat data seems ok shape is 56, each just to asure numeric values

xp, yp, _ = mapcrs.transform_points(datacrs, lon, lat).T

x_masked, y_masked, dat = remove_nan_observations(xp, yp, dat)

gridx, gridy, gridz = interpolate_to_grid(x_masked, y_masked, dat, interp_type='cressman', minimum_neighbors=1, search_radius=40000, hres=5000)
#command in notebook ok no errors

import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mapcrs)
ax.contourf(gridx,gridy,gridz,np.arange(0,35.1,1))
```

this generate an error
**TypeError: Input z must be at least a (2, 2) shaped array, but has shape (1, 1)**

as new to python and metpy have struggled with the solution, thanks for any help.

**EDITED:
Thanks @dopplerShift, that was the thing, here is the fix and the result

```
gridx, gridy, gridz = interpolate_to_grid(lon, lat, dat, interp_type='cressman', minimum_neighbors=1, search_radius=.75, hres=.1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is this line from the docs:

> hres (float) – The horizontal resolution of the generated grid, given in the same units as the x and y parameters. Default 50000.

Here you pass `hres=5000`, which is saying "generate a grid with 5000 units between points". For points coming through a map projection, this is generally meters, ***except*** that you're using `PlateCarree()`, where the points are given in degrees. So for your current map projection, you should use an `hres` value in degrees, so maybe 0.25 or 0.1. You'll also want to adjust `search_radius` to a value in degrees (rather than the current 40km) as well--or leave it out and it will try to calculate something sensible.